# ds-160 - how can I include 2 different types of old visas?

Tags: visas, usa, applications

I am filling out the DS-160 format. When asked to fill in the data for my last visa issued I want to include two of them but don´t know how. My last issued visa is a type J (which has already expired), however I´m trying to renew my B type visa (which is about to expire and was issued earlier than the J one).
Thanks for the help!
Liz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks for the date your last visa was issued. That will be your J visa. You don't need to enter other visa information: you can safely assume that USCIS will be able to retrieve the details of prior visas.